# Using React : Passing data from SearchBar component to Widget1 component

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing a dashboard about covid and I use an API.
I have 2 distinct components : SearchBar and Widget1.
**What I want to do is to get the user input (a country name) from the input (located in SearchBar) and pass it to Widget1 so it can make a correct request to the API.** I made a callback function so that widget1 could get the country name. But when I call it inside the search funtion (located in Widget1) it return undefined instead of what's in the input.
Here's my code :

Widget1:

```
import React from "react";
import SearchBar from "../SearchBar";

// const API_URL = "https://api.covid19tracking.narrativa.com/api/2021-11-25/country/France";


export default class Widget1 extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            post: [],
            error: undefined,
            country: undefined
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.search();
    }
    search = async () => {

        this.setState({ country: this.getCountry() })  //récupère la valeur dans le champ
        // if (country === "") country = "France"; //Pays par défaut
        console.log("search" + this.state.country);
        const url = "https://api.covid19tracking.narrativa.com/api/2021-11-25/country/" + this.state.country;
        try {
            if (this.state.country) {
                const response = await fetch(url); //Fais une requête
                const data = await response.json(); //fichier .json avec les résultats de la requête
                console.log(data.dates["2021-11-25"].countries[this.state.country]);
                this.setState({
                    post: data.dates["2021-11-25"].countries[this.state.country],
                    error: ""
                })
            }
            else {

                this.setState({
                    post: [],
                    error: "Please enter a country name"
                })
            }
        } catch (err) {
            if (err.response) {
                console.log(err.response.data);
                this.setState({
                    post: [],
                    error: err.response.data.message
                });
            }
        }

    }
    // GetListCountry = async (array) => {
    //     const url = "https://api.covid19tracking.narrativa.com/api/countries";
    //     const response = await fetch(url);
    //     const data = await response.json();

    //     const array = data.countries
    // }
    getCountry = (country_child) => {

        const country = country_child;
        console.log(country + "blabla");
        //return (country_child);
    }
    render() {
        if (this.state.error !== undefined && this.state.post !== []) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <SearchBar search={this.search} getCountryCall={this.getCountry.bind(this)} />
                    <div className="container">
                        <article className="NbrCles">
                            <h2> Chiffres Clés : {this.state.post.name} </h2>
                            <header>
                                <p>Nombre de cas depuis le début de l'épidémie :</p>
                                <p>Nombre de décès depuis le début de l'épidémie :</p>
                            </header>
                            <div className="row">
                                <p>{this.state.post.today_confirmed}</p>
                                <p>{this.state.post.today_deaths}</p>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
        else {
            return (
                <div>
                    <div className="error">{this.state.error}</div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

SearchBar:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            inputValue: ''
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form className="form-container" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                    <input id="country-input" type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Rentrer le nom d'un pays" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <div>
                        <button id="country-input-button" className="btn btn-success" type="submit">Actualiser</button>

                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value });
    }
    getCountryChild = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

    }
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state.inputValue + "lalalalalal");

        this.props.search();
        this.props.getCountryCall(this.state.inputValue);
    }
}
```

What I get in the console when typing India in the input :

- SearchBar.js:33 Indialalalalalal
- Covid_API.js:64 undefinedblabla
- Covid_API.js:24 searchundefined
- Covid_API.js:64 Indiablabla

Comment: I'm taking a look through your code and just have a quick question to make sure I can give you the correct fix. Are you trying to pass the country data from SearchBar to Widget1 while typing the data or only when you press submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright well assuming you wanted to pass data through as you type (like I asked in my comment) I have fixed up your code and cleaned it up to do what I believe you want.

Your new Widget1 class looks like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import SearchBar from "../SearchBar";

//const API_URL =("https://api.covid19tracking.narrativa.com/api/2021-11-25/country/France");

export default class Widget1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      post: {},
      error: "",
      country: undefined
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.search();
  }
  search = async () => {
    // if (country === "") country = "France"; //Pays par défaut

    // I cleaned up your url using a template literal
    const url = `https://api.covid19tracking.narrativa.com/api/2021-11-25/country/${this.state.country}`;

    try {
      if (this.state.country) {
        const response = await fetch(url); //Fais une requête
        const data = await response.json(); //fichier .json avec les résultats de la requête

        // Check if the returned country is the correct country that was searched
        if (
          Object.keys(
            data.dates["2021-11-25"].countries
          )[0].toLocaleLowerCase() === this.state.country.toLowerCase()
        ) {
          // If it is, then set your post state to the values (at index 0 since were comparing to the key at index 0)
          this.setState({
            post: Object.values(data.dates["2021-11-25"].countries)[0],
            error: ""
          });
        } else {
          // If not then reset your post state and set an error message
          this.setState({
            post: {},
            error: "Please enter a country name"
          });
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.response) {
        console.log(err.response.data);
        // this.setState({
        //   post: [],
        //   error: err.response.data.message
        // });
      }
    }
  };
  // GetListCountry = async (array) => {
  //     const url = "https://api.covid19tracking.narrativa.com/api/countries";
  //     const response = await fetch(url);
  //     const data = await response.json();

  //     const array = data.countries
  // }
  getCountry = (country_child) => {
    this.setState({ country: country_child });
  };
  render() {
    if (this.state.error !== undefined && this.state.post !== []) {
      return (
        <div>
          <SearchBar
            search={this.search}
            getCountryCall={this.getCountry.bind(this)}
          />
          <div className="container">
            <article className="NbrCles">
              <h2> Chiffres Clés : {this.state.post.name} </h2>
              <header>
                <p>Nombre de cas depuis le début de l'épidémie :</p>
                <p>Nombre de décès depuis le début de l'épidémie :</p>
              </header>
              <div className="row">
                <p>{this.state.post.today_confirmed}</p>
                <p>{this.state.post.today_deaths}</p>
              </div>
            </article>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="error">{this.state.error}</div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

And your new SearchBar class looks like this:

```js
import React from "react";

export default class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputValue: ""
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form
          className="form-container"
          onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
        >
          <input
            id="country-input"
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Rentrer le nom d'un pays"
            onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
          />
          <div>
            <button
              id="country-input-button"
              className="btn btn-success"
              type="submit"
            >
              Actualiser
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
  handleChange = (e) => {
    // Simplified this to pass the data back each time you type
    this.props.getCountryCall(e.target.value);
  };
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.search();
  };
}
```

I have done this on CodeSandBox so you can take a look at it all and test it easier if you would like:

[image: Edit xenodochial-ramanujan-60ns2]

The biggest change I really made was making sure your post state was a dictionary rather then an array object. The API call returns a JSON object back so when you try to set your array state to a dictionary value it would not allow you to call something like `<h2> Chiffres Clés : {this.state.post.name} </h2>` later as you would need to pass in the array index of the post to get the name.

Everything should work according to what you wanted now. If you have any questions with what I did or if there is something that isn't working the way you would like please let me know!

Comment: Thank you ! Works like a charm ! Do you have any suggestion if I wanted to move my search bar out of the Widget1 and put it directly in App so every other Widget (component) can access the value ?

Comment: @420BeginnerDev if you wanted to move the search bar directly into App, I feel like the best approach would be to store your states within the App so that they can be accessed and utilized across all other components. Then you would just have to pass them into each component as well as the appropriate functions to change them if needed.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought but it would take too much time x). I must present that project in 8 hours ^^. Thanks for the help man ! But don't worry I'll do it after, I don't like to let unfinished projects.